# What do the colours of functions in MySQL Workbench signify?

Tags: mysql, function, workbench

In MySQL Workbench, there are a lot of built-in functions for performing different tasks. Some functions are just synonyms. But I notice that synonymous functions sometimes have different color representations. Like, curdate() is grey and current_date() is blue. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) says that they are synonyms. So is there any specific reason behind the color codes here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blue means the word has meaning without parentheses.

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE; -- '2021-10-24'
```

If you try the same with CURDATE it will fail without parentheses.

I came across the same behavior when calling the string function REPLACE. Here we can't call REPLACE without parentheses, but it is used in the REPLACE INTO statement.